# How to get the file size while it is written on the sd?

Tags: java, android, buffer

Please, help me. I need to get full file size and already writed in while loop. I need this to set progress of my progress bar.
This is my code:

```
            try {
            URL u = new URL(imgUrl);
              InputStream is = u.openStream();

              DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);

              byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
              int length;
              File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                      + File.separator + "saved" + File.separator);
                    root.mkdirs();
                    String name = "" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, name);
                    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);


            while ((length = dis.read(buffer))>0) {
                  output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
                  Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "malformed url error", mue);
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                  Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "io error", ioe);
                } catch (SecurityException se) {
                  Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "security error", se);
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the number of bytes you already have written, use something like this:

Add a variable called `writtenBytes` before your while loop:

```
long writtenBytes = 0L;
```

Then, in your while loop, add the following code:

```
while ((length = dis.read(buffer))>0) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    writtenBytes += length;
}
```

To get the file size before downloading your file, you'll have to change your downloading code to something like:

```
URL url = new URL(imgUrl);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();

int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
```